# Removing a package from composer with --no-update

Tags: composer-php

I'm trying to remove a package from my application and I've run `composer remove --no-update package/name`, now all this does is remove the entry in `composer.json` but when I run `composer show -i`, I see the package is still installed, is there anyway to completely remove a package without running update?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is exactly what the `--no-update` option is intended to do.

`composer remove package/name` should remove `package/name` from your project without updating other packages than `package/name`.
It's the same if you remove the entry from your `composer.json` and then run `composer update package/name`. It will update this specific package but no others!

If you activate the `--no-update` option it omits the update, so it only removes the entry.

Comment: No it actually tried to updated all of the dependencies, I had to manually remove then update the package.

Comment: I did another test and yes you are half right and I am half wrong. It looks like `composer remove` removes the entry and then performs an `composer install` which means it will install/remove all packages listed/unlisted in `composer.json` but it definitely sticks to the versions from the `composer.lock`. So It does not perform a `composer update` but a `composer install` which make a huge difference.

Comment: Actually, based on my testing, I can confirm that `composer remove` does indeed do a `composer update`. Well, technically, according to the documentation (https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#remove), it does `--update-with-dependencies` now by default, which will update dependencies of the removed packages.

So you can disable the dependency update by running `composer remove --no-update-with-dependencies`

Answer (score 0):

I think what the --no-update option is intended to do is, this will avoid composer update.

for eg `composer require "magento/magento-cloud-metapackage":">=2.3.3 <2.3.4" --no-update` only update composer.json file not composer.lock file

while    composer require "magento/magento-cloud-metapackage":">=2.3.3 <2.3.4" 
    updates both **composer.json** and **composer.lock** file

Comment: When we upgrade to the next version means, why we need to put --no-update... Why don't we run without "--no-update"